# store API response data in first page and access in another page after reloading the page Polymer

Tags: javascript, web, web-applications, polymer, polymer-1.0

I get a sign in Response on the first page which I store in a Javascript local variable and I will pass the same data to the second page it works fine until I reload the second page,  but when I reload,the data which I got from the first page is destroyed.Storing the entire response-data in local storage is not good practice,If I store that data in session storage even anyone can modify data, So where we can store secured response data which I need in entire application and also which will not destroy when page is reloaded?

Comment: "If I store that data in session storage even anyone can modify data". If "anyone" means "anyone who uses your application", then you are probably thinking wrong about security. Everything in the browser is unsecured from the user. You have to apply security on the server side.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks, I got your point. but Is it fine to store response data in session storage? or is there any other alternate so even when the browser is refreshed the data should not destroy! I'm using Polymer js

Comment: "response data" if this are the codes for the nukes, I wouldn't send them in a response in the first place. In fact you shouldn't send **any** data in a response the user must not see. If it's fine for the user to see the data, then session storage is fine as well.